# Is it impossible to combine `repeat()` and `while()` to loop 3 times?

Tags: kotlin

I am new to Kotlin. How do I combine `repeat()` and `while()` to loop? I know how to loop by using following 2 methods:

```kotlin
// Method 1
    for (i in 1..3) {
        fortune = getFortune(getBirthday())
        println("\nYour fortune is: $fortune")
        if (fortune.contains("Take it easy")) break;
    }
```

```kotlin
// Method 2
    var fortune: String = ""
    var i: Int = 0 //i = 0
   while (!fortune.contains("Take it easy") && i<3 ) {
        fortune = getFortune(getBirthday())
        println("\nYour fortune is: $fortune")
        i += 1 // i++
    }
```

But I don't know how to combine `repeat()` and `while()` to loop. What I wrote below does NOT exit the loop at the 3rd times but will exit ONLY when the fortune string contains "Take it easy".

What I want is to exit the loop at either the 3rd time of entering your birthday or the fortune string contains "Take it easy". What I wrote below doesn't exit the loop at the 3rd time of entering your birthday. Is it impossible to combine `repeat()` and `while()` to loop 3 times?

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var fortune: String = ""
    repeat(3) {
        while (!fortune.contains("Take it easy")) {
            fortune = getFortune(getBirthday())
            println("\nYour fortune is: $fortune")
        }
    }
}
fun getBirthday(): Int {
    print("\nEnter your birthday: ")
    return readLine()?.toIntOrNull() ?: 1
}
fun getFortune(birthday: Int): String {
    val fortunes = listOf("You will have a great day!",
            "Things will go well for you today.",
            "Enjoy a wonderful day of success.",
            "Be humble and all will turn out well.",
            "Today is a good day for exercising restraint.",
            "Take it easy and enjoy life!",
            "Treasure your friends, because they are your greatest fortune.")
    val index = when (birthday) {
        in 1..7 -> 4
        28, 31 -> 2
        else -> birthday.rem(fortunes.size)
    }
    return fortunes[index]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: What do you mean by "repeat this while loop for 3 times"? It looks like you're already limiting to 3 loop turns. Do you want to repeat this whole processing 3 times?

Comment: You guys are awesome. This is the 1st time I asked a question here so I kind of slow. I rewrite my question. Pls read my question one more time!!

Comment: Please share more details - what do you want to achieve? What is not working yet?

Comment: I'm not entirely certain that I understand, but here's a guess: change `while` to `if`

Comment: Thank you for your help but my question is how to combine repeat() and while to loop. Is it impossible to combine repeat() and while() to loop 3 times? Pls read my question again. Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to combine both to make it loop 3 times. You would use one or the other. When you nest loops like this, it's like multiplying them. The outer `repeat` happens 3 times, so the inner `while` loop will **loop all the way through from the beginning** 3 times. However, in your example, your criterion for exiting the loop will be immediately satisfied the second two times so there will be no output from those subsequent runs.

Basically, if you have a repeating action but you have multiple conditions for when to finish it, the solution is not to add another loop, but instead you must add the additional logic for exiting the loop.

Since `repeat` is not a keyword, but rather it is a higher-order function, it is more complicated to exit the loop and doing so makes the code hard to read. So I don't recommend using `repeat` if you have any conditions for exiting the loop early. To exit it early, you have to do something like wrapping it in the `run` scope function so you can return from that scope function to break out of the loop:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var fortune: String = ""
    run loop@{
        repeat(3) {
            if (fortune.contains("Take it easy")) {
                return@loop
            }
            fortune = getFortune(getBirthday())
            println("\nYour fortune is: $fortune")
        }
    }
}
```

Much simpler to use a `for` loop than using `repeat` if you want to break out early, as shown in @evadeflow's answer, since you can use the `break` keyword.

Comment: You pointed my problem exactly. Thank you very much! I didn't know I can use only one of repeat() and while(). Although my codes will NOT immediately satisfied the second two times and there will be outputs from those subsequent runs until my criterion is fulfilled. The inner while() loop will keep running till my criterion is met so the repeat(3) becomes meaninglessly.

Comment: I appreciate your time in answering my question. Since you have spent time, you must think my question have some value. Would you please up vote this question? This question will benefit others in the future as well.

Comment: Your questions seem fine to me. I think it’s possible someone is downvoting your questions because your avatar is borderline NSFW and this is a web site that is primarily used in professional settings.

Answer (score 1):

```
   for(i in 0..2){
        println(i);
    }
```

Comment: You are great. This is the 1st time I asked a question here so I didn't write it clear enough. I already know how to use for loop but I don't know how to combine repeat() and while loop. Pls look at my question one more time!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't entirely understand what you're trying to accomplish, but I *think* you're saying you want to execute the loop until either:

1. The `fortune` string contains "Take it easy", *or*:
2. The loop has executed three times

I'm no Kotlin expert, but I don't believe it's possible to use a `break` statement inside a `repeat` loop, so you'll need to do something like this instead:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var fortune: String
     for (i in 1..3) {
        fortune = getFortune(getBirthday())
        println("\nYour fortune is: $fortune")
        if (fortune.contains("Take it easy")) {
          break
        }
    }
}
```

This will execute the loop a maximum of three times, but it may exit earlier if `fortune` contains "Take it easy".

Comment: You understand my goal correctly. Thank you for your reply and you can see from my question, your method is the same as my method 1.  From the topic of my question, you can see I want to combine repeat() and while to achieve my goal. Is it impossible to use repeat() and while to achieve my goal?